# Attribute Error from tensorboard.py following v0.7.1 upgrade

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorboard, tensorflow-serving

I just ran at my home directory:

```
sudo pip install --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/tensorflow-0.7.1-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl
```

Now when I try to run tensorboard using

```
tensorboard --logdir=/home/tattoo/Tabor_Stuff
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/tensorboard", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/tensorboard/tensorboard.py", line 117, in main
    multiplexer = event_multiplexer.AutoloadingMultiplexer(
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'AutoloadingMultiplexer'
tattoo@tattoo-OptiPlex-780:~/Tabor_Stuff$ cd ..
tattoo@tattoo-OptiPlex-780:~$ tensorboard --logdir=/home/tattoo/Tabor_Stuff
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/tensorboard", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/tensorboard/tensorboard.py", line 117, in main
    multiplexer = event_multiplexer.AutoloadingMultiplexer(
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'AutoloadingMultiplexer'
```

Has anyone else had v0.7.1 mess up tensorboard? Also am I missing a step on the install?

Comment: So I uninstalled and reinstalled tensorflow with the following commands. (Thanks to Vijay) pip uninstall protobuf     pip uninstall tensorflow pip install url/to the/tensorflow-...whl

Comment: **The board is displayed with** python /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/tensorboard/backend/tensorboard.py --logdir=/home/tattoo/Tabor12/Tabor1
**but with these errors**
WARNING:tensorflow:IOError [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/tensorboard/TAG' on path /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/tensorboard/TAG
WARNING:tensorflow:Unable to read TensorBoard tag
Starting TensorBoard  on port 6006
(You can navigate to http://0.0.0.0:6006)

Comment: Had the same problem after I thought I'd successfully upgraded to 0.7.1 from 0.6.0. There are three directories left untouched by the uninstall script. I changed the folder name to keep a backup in case the reinstall does not help. Thankfully, there were no issues with the reinstall. So, I'd recommend you to navigate to the folder and manually delete the tensorflow folder to ensure reinstall works as expected.

Comment: @McMDA, strange that you have `tensorboard.py` in `/backend`; I have in just `/tensorflow/tensorboard`.